# file upload issue in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, dojo

I have a Dojo front-ended web application. Whenever I try to post a form with file attachment, a notification pops up saying "Verifying Application Requirements", stays for a while and then times out with another notification indicating "Application download did not succeed......". I noticed this behaviour on IE8. I could not come up with any satisfying answer on the web. Most of the answers seemed to indicate that this notification comes up for ClickOnce applications (whatever they are). Bwt, the OS is Windows 7.

Does anybody know a solution or the reason ?[image: Screen shot of the notification]

Comment: An update: On debugging the request through Fiddler, I noticed that request does indeed land to the server and it responds. However before my application could handle the response, another process dfsvc sends a GET request to the URL that was previously POsTed by the form. It is obvious that this process is trying to download from this URL as required by ClickOnce applications. How can I stop this behaviour, since my application is just a simple web app and not a ClickOnce or .NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED!!! IE8 was sending the "Accept" header as application/x-ms-application and the response was also coming back with the same content-type and windows was considering the response as a MS application. It worked properly after I explicitly set the Content-Type to "text/html" in the response. Unfortunately, we cannot set the header in dojo.io.iframe.send params. Hope this solution helps somebody with similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to fix issue with dojo fileUploader and IE8 it's just adding `"produces = "text/html; charset=utf-8"`" to your controller like this:

`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/attach", produces = "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String attach() {
    };`

Answer (score 0):

This Q&A was **very** helpful for me. I had the same issue with Win 7 + IE8, specifically when trying to upload files with `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`.

I resolved the issue by adding `produces = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"` to my `@RequestMapping( ... )` declaration.