# Internet Explorer giving Malformed JSON in response body

Tags: json, internet-explorer

I'm using ajaxSubmit to upload a file a in a page and return the contents of the file in the form of jsonString from the controllers to fill some dropdowns...
I'm using spring 3.0 framework,jquery 1.5.2 and Jackson JSON.
The problem is that i'm getting a invalid jsonstring in response body in internet explorer, but proper jsonstring in firefox and chrome.
The json content is a little lengthy and i'm printing out the jsonString in the console at the controller just before returning, that also seems to be proper.
I've googled this issue but all i found was that IE has some internal mechanism to remove control characters from the json.I've checked my jsonString it has no control characters

P.S: I'm using IE10 and testing my application in different modes.IE8 standard mode and IE10 compatibility mode and all other modes are giving me an invalid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!!
The problem with spring is that when your using @ResponseBody annotation you can't set the response content type in the response object explicitly.
[This post explains an alternative to that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879073/2831032)